# Slow romance novel (asian chinese or korean) about a woman who is transmigrated or reincarnated to a historical period

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

The female lead is transmigrated or reincarnated to a historical period . It's a slow romance novel where the male lead fell first for her and is insecure about her feelings for him.

A scene that marked me was when they reunited; the male lead saw her with another man and he was jealous. That led to a fight between the leads and the female lead went to forest after the dispute. She met a woman who was an enemy of a mother and tried to kill her. She is almost killed by her when the male lead arrives in the forest. He is deeply regretful and tries everything to protect and cure her.

To cure her, the male lead brought her to her master, who put her in a big cauldron and medical things. She is alive but really fragile.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Possibly the Outlander novel/series? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlander_(book_series)

Comment: Thank you but it's not this one